# Autopopulate Custom field when Lead is converting

Tags: custom-field, leads, convert

When I am converting Lead I wants to auto populate field before lead is converting screen.

In Lead I am have custom field named "Campaign name" and In task section I have created custom field named "Campaign Name". when I am click on convert button on lead detail page it will redirect to converting page in this page I wants to auto filled up lead campaign name field into task campaign name.

Please Suggest.

Answer (score 1):

For standard fields check [this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-do-i-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-layout), and for custom fields you need to write a bit of code and override the standard pages (new/edit) depending on your scenario.

[Here](http://force201.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/hack-to-find-field-ids-allows-a-default-ui-new-page-to-be-pre-populated/) you can see how it's done using custom fields. It's still technically a "hack" but I think I've read somewhere recently that Salesforce might add support for this over the next few releases.