# Communication between Custom Console Component and a standard Salesforce page?

Tags: service-cloud-console

I am new to salesforce and I am facing a problem.
I will try to be as clear as possible. So here is my problem:

I have created a Custom Console Component and add it into my Service Cloud Console BUT I want this Custom Component to be able to populate the fields in the Account creation form.
For example, let's say the user clicks inside a field and it opens a popup and inside that popup the user is able to type anything he want and when he clicks a button to validate his typing, the field will be populated with what he has previously typed inside the popup. Is this possible? Many thanks.

This form:

[image: New Account form]

So, I would like to know if it is possible to achieve that?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The service cloud console have nothing to do with prepopulating fields on the edit layout of some object. For that you can use default field values. These value are calculated every time the user clicks on the "New" button of the object.

More info about it: [About Default Field Values](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_default_field_values.htm&language=en_US)

Another solution is to use a custom "New" button and do field prepopulation with URL parameter.

More info about prepopulation with URL params: [How do I prepopulate fields on a Standard layout?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/937/how-do-i-prepopulate-fields-on-a-standard-layout)

Comment: Hi mast0r,  Thank you for your quick answer but I don't want these values to be the same each times.  I will rephrase what I want.  For example, let's say the user clicks inside a field and it opens a popup and inside that popup the user is able to type anything he want and when he clicks a button to validate his typing, the field will be populated with what he has previously typed inside the popup.  Is this possible?  Many thanks.